# плавающий баннер на jQuery...

Tags: jquery

Нигде не встречаю плавающих баннеров с выключателем на jQuery. Подскажите плиз если кто встречал. Буду очень признателен...

Comment: Что такое "плавающий баннер"?

Answer (score 1):

Зависит от баннеров. К примеру, `$('#logo img').remove();` на Хэшкоде отключит логотип. Поэтому если вам нужно отключить какие-либо всплывающие баннеры у себя на сайте, посмотрите их код и напишите отключатель.